# appending element to an empty array using a new one from another method

Tags: java, arrays

As the code shows field os an empty array that I want to populate with the value l from another method I used arraycopy method and set the first array to point to the new added value but the output is gibberish .

Output:

```
[J@7dc5e7b4
```

I have tried with `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(field));` but all it prints out is this [] empty brackets.

```java
import java.util.*;

public class Aufgabe_04_02 {

    static long[] field = new long[]{};
    
    static void add(long l) {
        long[] f1 = new long[field.length + 1];
        System.arraycopy(field, 0, f1, 0, field.length);
        f1[0]= l;
        field= f1;  
    }// end add(longl)
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long[] result = field;
        System.out.println(result);
    }// end main
 
}// end class
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the simplest way to print a Java array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-a-java-array)

Comment: You initialize `field` as an empty `long[]`. You then assign `long[] result = field`. So `result` now references an empty `long[]` as well. You then print `result`, which then of course prints an empty array. What are you expecting? You might want to call your `add()` method.

Comment: actually i commented out the lines where result is initialized and printed I called field directly using System.out.println(Arrays.toString(field)); and that still prints an empty array.

Comment: so what you are saying is call add() instead of field, but the goal is to call field and print the value added in add()

Answer (score 1):

In java, print arrays using `Arrays.toString()`. However, there is more to be fixed here.

You initialize `field` as an empty `long[]`. After that, you assign `long[] result = field`. So `result` now references an empty `long[]` as well. You then print `result`, which then of course prints an empty array.

To see your array change, yo might want to actually call your `add()` method.

For example:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    add(1);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(field));
}
```

Which then prints:

```
[1]
```

However you have an issue in your `add()` method. If you add more than one value, it  always overwrites the value at index 0. Due to this line: `f1[0]= l`

So, what you might actually want to do is to add the new value at the end of the array, meaning at the index that you just increased by 1.

So you want to change this line of code:

```java
f1[0] = l;
```

to

```java
f1[field.length] = l;
```

The "final" snippet:

```java
static long[] field = new long[] {};

static void add(long l) {
    long[] f1 = new long[field.length + 1];
    System.arraycopy(field, 0, f1, 0, field.length);
    f1[field.length] = l;
    field = f1;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    add(1);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(field));
    add(3);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(field));
}
```

Prints the following output:

```
[1]
[1, 3]
```

Comment: okay i get it thanks man that was very helpful

Comment: @kololo you are welcome. If this answers your questions, feel free to accept / vote the answer. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).